# How do I get data inside table / td

Tags: javascript

I use code below for get the cell value.

```
alert(document.getElementById("table-body-positions").rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML);
```

Td value is

```
<td><a data-action="details"><span><span class="">2019/01/04 13:36:19</span></span></a></td>
```

I get result this.

```
<a data-action="details"><span><span class="">2019/01/04 13:36:19</span></span></a>
```

But I just want to get 2019/01/04 13:36:19

Same problem here for this td.

```
<td><a data-action="update-limit" data-filter="limit">1.18809 (505.4)<br>$808.64</a></td>
```

Comment: well you are reading the innerHTML when you want to read the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of InnerHTML, you can use innerText

```js
alert(document.getElementById("table-body-positions").rows[0].cells[1].innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find each `td` by tag name and then recursively check its contents until a `nodeType` `TEXT_NODE` is found.

This works best if you do not have a fixed HTML structure within your tds as it would appear.

No ids and no classes needed.

```js
function recursiveSearch(elem){
   
   if(elem.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE){
     //text was discovered
     return elem.data.replace("\n", "").trim();
   }
   const nodes = elem.childNodes;
   return Object.keys(nodes).map(key=>recursiveSearch(nodes[key])).join("");
}

const tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
const res = Object.keys(tds).map(key=>{
  const td = tds[key];
  return recursiveSearch(td);
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    <a data-action="details">
      <span>
    <span class="">2019/01/04 13:36:19</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a data-action="update-limit" data-filter="limit">
  1.18809 (505.4)<br>$808.64
   </a>
  </td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could add a unique id, or class name to the span you are interested in.

Use innerText rather than innerHTML.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText)
```

```html
<table>
<td><a data-action="details"><span><span class="">2019/01/04 13:36:19</span></span></a></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems over complicated just to get innerHTML alerts. Here is my solution. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyWqaX?editors=1010#0)

HTML

```
<table id = "table-body-positions">
    <tr>
    <td><a data-action="details"><span><span id = "details">2019/01/04 13:36:19</span></span></a></td>
    <td><a data-action="update-limit" data-filter="limit"><span id = "limit">1.18809 (505.4)<br>$808.64</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
let details = document.getElementById("details").innerHTML;
let limit = document.getElementById("limit").innerText;

alert(details);
alert(limit);
```

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use span id instead of span class.I can't manipulate anything just call from another web site.Thank you for answer.